# What is the correct syntax of Delete(node ) for SLL in C?

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

Assuming the relevant header files, functions for Singly Linked List in C are declared.

Is the following definition of Delete() correct?

```
 /* The Structure for SLL 
     typedef struct SLL
     {
       int data;
       struct SLL *next;
      }node;
    Function Delete() deletes a node*/

    void Delete( node **head)
    {
      node *temp, *prev;
      int key;
      temp = *head;
      if(temp == NULL)
      {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
      }
      clrscr();
      printf("\nEnter the element you want to delete:");
      scanf("%d", &key);
      temp = search( *head , key);//search()returns the node which has key
     if(temp != NULL)
      {
         prev = get_prev(*head, key);
         if(prev != NULL)
         {
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
         }
         else
          {
             *head = temp->next;
              free(temp);
          }
          printf("\nThe node is deleted");
          getch();
       }
     }
```

1) What happens if I replace`(node ** head)` with `(node *head)`?

2) What happens if I replace void Delete `(node **head)` with node
`*Delete(node *head)`?

3) Is there an alternate way to delete a node in C?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should do some research about *passing arguments by value* and *emulating pass by reference in C*?

Comment: Yeah I did some research. I found the above code works as it should. I cannot understand the working behind it.

Comment: So you know how *emulating pass by reference in C* works? Then I don't really see the point of your first question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know what emulating pass by reference means.

Comment: _[Here is a good tutorial site for types of linked list manipulations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/)_  This particular page deals with deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you replace `node** head` with `node* head` you won't modify the original `head` pointer. You probably have a `head` somewhere that marks the beginning of the linked list. When you delete a node, there's a chance that you want to delete `head`. In that case you need to modify `head` to point to the next `node` in the linked list.

```
         *head = temp->next;
          free(temp);
```

This part of your code does exactly that. Here, `temp == head`. We want `head` to point to `head->next`, but if we pass in `node* head` to the function, the pointer will get modified but the changes will disappear because you're passing the pointer by value. You need to pass in `&head` which will be of type `node ** head` if you want the changes to be reflected outside of the function.

2) You will then change the function definition to return a void pointer (which is a placeholder pointer that can be converted to any pointer. Take care to not break any aliasing rules with this. But the problem from (1) remains, although, you could return a modified head, and assign it to the returned value. In that case define the function won't fit well with other cases where the head doesn't need to be modified. So you could return a pointer for head if it's modified or return NULL when it doesnt. It's a slightly messier method of doing things imho, though.

3) Yes, but that depends on the way a linked list is implemented. For the datatype shown here, the basic delete operation is as given.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: I have some residual doubts.. 1)passing a pointer to a function doesn't mean that its address is passed too? So, what you mean to say is that (node **head) is same as (node *(&head)) , but not for (node *head)?

Comment: @AndrewJoel No prob :)

Comment: @AndrewJoel Not quite. There's this pointer and let's call it `t`. We want to change the pointer itself (ie the address that's stored in it, not the thing it ints to) in a function. That obviously means we need to pass it by reference, and in C we use pointers to do that, so you'd need to pass in `&t` which is of type `typeof(t) *`. Here `t` is a pointer of `struct node`, so it's type is `node*`, so the parameter we pass into it must be of type `node**`. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Oh okay. So by default in C, any pointer can be pointed by itself if i use ** as its prefix?

Comment: No, that's the type of the pointer. `type**` simply means it's a pointer to a pointer to a node. You always use `&variable` to get its address.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a tutorial site, but here goes...

You do know that arguments in C are passed *by value*? Meaning the value is *copied*.

For example:

```
void some_function(int a)
{
    // ...
}
```

When calling the function above, like

```
int x = 5;
some_function(x);
```

Then the value in `x` is copied into the argument `a` in the function. If the code inside the function assigns to `a` (e.g. `a = 12;`) then you only modify the local variable `a`, the copy. It does not modify the original variable.

Now, if we *want* the function to modify `x`, then we must emulate *pass by reference*, which is done using pointers and the address-of operator:

```
void some_function(int *a)
{
    *a = 12;  // Modify where a is pointing
}
```

Now to call that, we don't create a pointer variable and pass that (though it's possible as well), instead we use the address-of operator `&` to pass a pointer to the variable:

```
int x = 5;
some_function(&x);  // Pass a pointer to the variable x
```

The pointer `&x` *will be passed by value* (since that's the only way to pass arguments in C), but we don't want to modify the pointer, we want to modify the data *where it points*.

---

Now back to your specific function: Your function wants to modify a variable which is a pointer, then how do we emulate pass by reference? By passing a pointer *to the pointer*.

So if you have

```
node *head;
// Initialize head, make it point somewhere, etc.
```

Now since the `Delete` function needs to modify where `head points, we pass a pointer to`head`, a pointer to the pointer:

```
Delete(&head);
```

The `Delete` function of course must accept that type, a pointer to a pointer to `node`, i.e. `node **`. It then uses the dereference operator `*` to get where the pointer is pointing:

```
*head = temp->next;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation.

Comment: @ryyker Well maybe some of my answers tend to be a little "tutorial-y", and maybe I should refrain from writing so many of them (or at least not write it here). Then on the other hand, writing tutorials on other places and then add comments here linking to them seems like a little selfish and egocentric. And I I just can't be bothered to write more detailed and extensive tutorials, the "answer" here is just about all I can muster on a good day. :)